# AWS SNS push notifications way overpriced?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, push-notification, amazon-sns

I feel like I am missing something. I am evaluating what the costs would be for push notifications for a large social app like Instagram.
 Let's say we have 150,000,000 users (large, I know, but this is an example situation). Let's also say that each user receives 200 push notifications per month. 
With the [AWS SNS pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/pricing/), this usage would cost $30,000 per month! (150,000,000*200)/1,000,000 (AWS charges per million requests - 50c per publish and 50c per delivery)  = $30,000. There may even be data transfer charges that I'm not factoring in.  
 If I were to use a service like [Parse Push](https://www.parse.com/plans), who charges unique recipients per month, the savings would be massive. It would cost $7,450 to serve ***unlimited*** notifications to 150,000,000 unique users per month. ($0.05 per 1000 users over 1mil per month) That's almost a quarter the price of AWS for unlimitedly more notifications. 
 How do these services even compete at this price difference?

Comment: they probably compete by providing reliable service through distributed server network, storage of messages, promise that if half of network will die in US, your messages will be re-routed via Europe

Comment: When you find an apparently massive discrepancy like this, the best course of action usually to realize that you are failing to account for *something*.  Parse appears to have a charge of $100/mo for each 10 API reqs/sec of provisioned capacity over baseline.  SNS has nothing like that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you are calculating the price correctly, because a single delivery could be triggered by a single publish if multiple subscribers are on the topic. This help with scenario's like regional events, but wouldn't help so much with personal events like new friend requests.

If I have all 150 million subscribes on a single SNS topic, I would expect to be paying $75.50 every time I publish and publish a message. 150,000,000 deliveries @ $.50 per million = $75. Then add the cost of the 1 publish @ $.50. So if you only had one list your cost would be significantly less. It would always cost you $15,000 for delivering 150 million messages to 200 users, but it may only cost an additional $100 dollars if all of the users were on the same SNS topic and only 200 publishes were performed.

https://aws.amazon.com/sns/pricing/

> When you use SNS topics to broadcast identical messages to many
>   recipients at once, your effective price can be even lower than $1.00
>   per million mobile push notifications

[By the way parse push is shutting down.](https://www.parse.com/pricing)

Sometimes service providers don't advertise sustainable business models. Their prices are sometimes teaser rates which increase once you buy-in and build your application. Once you are actually sending 150 million messages 200 times a month $30k a month starts to look cheap when you consider the resources of that kind of operation.

Now you have to factor in the cost of migrating away from a volatile service provider. You need to fill at least three professional roles to do the migration: developer, quality assurance and project manager. That's going to quickly cut down any previous savings. I'm not just being theoretical here. I've had to do these kind of migrations in the past, because service providers did giant price increases.

I would not only expect the pricing in AWS to only go down over time, but I would also expect a high quality of service and support over the service's lifetime with AWS. Service quality and support is something you don't get to test until you are in production and have already implemented.

A big part of what you are paying for is *trust* in the service and that's not going to be reflected on any specification of what the service provides.

Answer (score 1):

If you'll consider even other providers, such as [PushApps](http://www.pushapps.mobi/#!pricing-push-notification-sdk/c1739), you'll find out that there are also unlimited notifications packages for 50$ per month.